# .net Reflector decompiled C# code won't compile

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

I tried to decompile a C# console application and compile it again in Visual C# 2010, but there are many errors in the code. Here is an example:

```
 public static Test mTest
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <mTest>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <mTest>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
```

I've set the .net framework version to 3.5 in .net Reflector. Is there any way to get code that is able to recompile from .net Reflector?

Comment: `<mTest>k__BackingField` are compiler generated internal field names and they can't be used as field names in your source code

Comment: What version of Resharper are you using?  The current versions understand this, and turn it into an auto-prop

Comment: Ok I tried it ... you're right that seems like a bug in Reflector.  The instance properties are fine - but the static ones are still adding the backing field.  The only way you'll be able to fix it (realistically) is to go through the code and replace the getters and setters with the { get; set; } - or rename the backing field to a valid c# field name.

Answer (score 4):

There is no straight way to overcome this limitation. Compiler created `IL` from your source code and this `IL` may **not** contain information regarding your initial source code. For example when you write

```
public string Property { get; set; }
```

Compiler creates backing field (for example `<Property >k__BackingField` ) and names it using special symbols, that you can't use to name your field in the source code. You gave the example above, where reflector tried to deduce what compiler meant.

I've used [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (free decompiler by JetBrains) and it understand autoproperties, so you would see correct code in your example. But again - there might be cases, where dotPeek won't be able to get the initial source code.

Comment: Is there any way to fix the code and make it compiling properly?

Comment: @user2196536 you should use `public static Test mTest { get; set; }` for that field