# Ways to recover lost VB.net application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, compilation, decompiling

I'm trying to recover lost code from a VB.net 2.0 application that I've inherited.  I have current working versions, so I've tried using RedGate Reflector and Telerik JustDecompile to recover the code.  Both will successfully return code files that are readable and Visual Studio project files, but when I try to run the decompiled program, I get 102 error messages (with both decompilers).

I have working Visual Studio projects from old versions, which run fine, but the structure of the solution and code files is completely different and I'm afraid the program was changed too much since then to trust these old versions.

The only odd assembly that was included is `SmartCodeDeveloper 1.0.2986.26049`.  And I suspect the code was originally written in Visual Studio 2005, as both 2008 and 2012 want to upgrade when the solution is opened.

What else can I do to recover this program?  I have the code, but something else is preventing it from running, and I'm at a deadend.

EDIT:

Some of the error messages I'm getting are:
-"End of Statement Expected" or "Statement cannot appear within an event body.  End of Event assumed."
-Many are variations on "RemoveHandler" definition missing for object.
-object not declared "It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

EDIT 2:
Is there any advantage to trying to decompile into C#?  Is it possible Reflector may do a better job converting to that?  What about different .NET framework versions?  I've been doing 2.0, which I believe it was developed on.

Comment: Are there 102 distinct error messages, or do they seem to be related? Could you throw a couple on here so we can get a better idea of what you might be missing?

Comment: Did you try adding the generated code files to a new project in the version is visual studio you own?

Comment: 102 is the max it will show, there could be many more.  but also some changes can fix multiple errors - like replacing a lost reference to something.  Also, start with OPTION STRICT off to eliminate those errors and see what the damage is just from the reverse engineering

Comment: @Plutonix, I've had some projects max out around 350 errors. It might be an environment setting, though.

Comment: @Plutonix -I usually work in C#, can you expand on how to set OPTION STRICT off in VB.net?  Is it similiar to doing so in VBA?  Where do I set this?

Comment: @MAW74656, I think it's off in each class by default. You can always just throw `Option Strict Off` at the very top of a file, though (just to be sure). Also, I'm pretty sure it's on a class-by-class basis (I don't know if it's available as a project-level setting)

Comment: Project properties -> Compile; its an option, so it could be on,

Comment: @Plutonix -It was on, but no change to error messages when off.  Same ones show at

Comment: yea, but it might have removed #103-206 depending whether it was written with it on or off.  what is the nature of them?

Comment: @Plutonix -Some repeated examples are in my edit.

Comment: @MikeCheel -Can you elaborate?  This project has over 100 code files.  How can I best add them to project?  Do I need to do "Add Existing Item" for each one?

Comment: You should be able to add multiple items.

Comment: if you blindly decompiled, then copy/pasted decompiled source code, it won't work.  There's usually some tweaking you need to do first before the decompiled code will once again successfully recompile.  How much you have to do, depends largely on the application that's being decompiled.

Comment: @MikeCheel -Getting 291 errors in the new project, many of them are the same, but lots of `"Statement cannot appear within an event body.  End of event assumed."`

Comment: @user2366842 -No, the decompiler gave me project files, so it wasn't just a blind copy/past.  Things I have to do.... such as?  I've check references, .NET framework target... I don't know what else to look at.

Comment: there very well may be certain symbols that need replacing with actual values...take a look at the answer posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555766/net-reflector-decompiled-c-sharp-code-wont-compile of the few times that i've had reason to decompile and then rebuild programs, i do recall there being some weird things that it spits out that had to be fixed (I recall seeing a fair amount of dollar symbols with values tied to them in a vb.net program for example - i believe this is how a decompiler deals with values it's not sure of)

Comment: That error indicates that some code is nested inside of other code (like a procedure being declared inside a procedure).

Comment: @MikeCheel -Then that nesting should be valid, because it was running just fine, right?  Unless decompilers just make things up...

Comment: @user2366842 -Not seeing any out of place dollar symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Reflector will create code that isn't VB code,  ie.  var++ .  You will have to find them and fix them.  It will also create many event definitions that won't work.  Look for code Like Public Custom Event definitions.  Delete the Custom keyword and all the lines following until End Event.  Also you will need to figure out what Import statements you need.

Here is an example from Reflector

```
 Public Custom Event ColumnChanging As DataColumnChangeEventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value As DataColumnChangeEventHandler)
        Bid.Trace("<ds.DataTable.add_ColumnChanging|API> %d#" & ChrW(10), Me.ObjectID)
        Me.onColumnChangingDelegate = DirectCast(Delegate.Combine(Me.onColumnChangingDelegate, value), DataColumnChangeEventHandler)
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As DataColumnChangeEventHandler)
        Bid.Trace("<ds.DataTable.remove_ColumnChanging|API> %d#" & ChrW(10), Me.ObjectID)
        Me.onColumnChangingDelegate = DirectCast(Delegate.Remove(Me.onColumnChangingDelegate, value), DataColumnChangeEventHandler)
    End RemoveHandler
End Event
```

It would be changed to this :

```
Public Event ColumnChanging As DataColumnChangeEventHandler
```

Missing References will cause many errors also.

Comment: Just delete the Public Custom Events?  Don't I need to change them or I'll loose the functionality?

Comment: I edited my previous answer to show more clearly what I meant.

Comment: So I may need to simply remove `Custom` if the line is the same otherwise?  Could a similar issue happen with `ReadOnly`?

Comment: I've not seen the ReadOnly problem but it seems possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this same problem once before. Described by another member.
Its really simple to correct.
The reason you have these 100+ errors is usually because of something trivial...
Like an unterminated strig for example.
Yet a simple error pushes everything else out of sync so you get more errors displayed than the actual amount of REAL errors, because of the ladder effect that ocurs due to the first error (cause of issue).

The BEST way to deal with it is as follows....

```
1 - Open your solution
2 - Close all document windows - so no solution documents are displayed
3 - Compile your solution
4 - At this point your errors should be minimised to a much lower amount of errors like maybe 1 to 10 for example.
```

Try that and let me know how many errors are listed AFTER you have done the above.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I guess it means your errors are all real and not a ladder effect after all.