# Decompiled с# code shows errors

Tags: c#

I have decompiled C# dll and now can not compile it. It shows strange errors, for example in some switch blocks some case blocks havent their break statements, or errors like "Can not cast int to bool" are shown. But the amount of errors is not very large for dll of that size, so I think it is not the problem of decompiler.

Is there some derective for compiler (for example, smthing life unsafe) that will solve this problem? Or why is there such strange errors?

P.S. The dll is not broken - the application is using it right now. I'm using dotPeek to decompile and Visual Studio 15 to compile the result code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15555859/4767498

Comment: Decompilers are never perfect.  And dotPeek certainly leads the pack in the not-perfect-decompilers category.  They are primarily meant to help diagnose unexpected behavior in a 3rd party library.  And to promote the company's other tools, the ones that actually brings in the money.  Violating somebody's copyright was never on top of the feature list.

Comment: @HansPassant Decompiling a dll you don't have the source to doesn't necessarily mean it's violating copyright.

Comment: @Rob No, but recompiling it already comes one step closer to violating copyright. Anyway, I think Hans' remark was meant to make clear that having it be fully recompilable is not their intended goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite hard to decompile IL to C# and decompiler has probably done something wrong. In my experience, decompiled and compiled code can also behave differently than original assembly, so be aware. And such compile error can be indocation that dotPeek was not sure, so think about it what it should do or look in IL.

If you are willing to make really small edits to the assembly (inject method calls, make something public) it may be safer to do it directly in IL obtained by `ildasm`.

Answer (score 1):

For such an error like :

```
"Can not cast int to bool"
```

There is absolutely no compiler directive that will allow your compiler to go ahead, I think that your decompiler messed up something decompiling ... You could simply try with another decompiler and see if you get another results, valid alternatives are : [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net), [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and [Dotnet IL Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/files/) .

Be aware that some commercial DLL is obfuscated just to try to make life difficult to the decompiler and to who decompile ...

*Be careful to avoid breaking some copyright .*